# glTextureSubImage{n}D with persistently mapped source buffer object

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

I just realized that in my application [glTextureSubImage{n}D](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml) results in the following error:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a non-zero buffer object name is
>   bound to the GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER target and the buffer object's
>   data store is currently mapped.

However, the pixel-unpack buffer has a persistent mapping and similar functions like [glCopyBufferSubData](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCopyBufferSubData.xhtml) allow copying from mapped buffers:

> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if either the source or destination
>   buffer object is mapped with glMapBufferRange or glMapBuffer, **unless
>   they were mapped with the GL_MAP_PERSISTENT bit set in the
>   glMapBufferRange access flags**.

My questions are:

1. Is there any special/hidden reason why glTextureSubImage{n}D is not able to handle persistently mapped buffers, or is it maybe just a bug/missing feature in the OpenGL 4.4 specification?
2. Is there a pattern or trick to update parts of a large texture **using persistently mapped** buffers?
   I can think of adding another buffer and first using glCopyBufferData and then glTextureSubImage on that buffer, but this is most likely slower than unmapping the pixel-unpack buffer before calling glTextureSubImage and then remapping the pixel-unpack buffer.

Comment: Your answer should be here: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object. Select 2.3.3 Persistent Mapping.

Comment: Indeed I only passed the persistent flag to glNamedBufferStorage and somehow forgot it in the glMapNamedBufferRange call. Your link was helpful as it pointed out that the flag needs to be set in both calls. However, the OpenGL specification of glTextureSubImage is unclear and misled me :(.  Feel free to submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.